Simplify a binomial expression and solve for $p$
I have this inequality that I wish to solve for $p$:
\begin{align*}
    &\mathbf{E}[X] \leq d \;\;\;\mathsf{where}\;\\
    &\mathbf{E}[X] = \sum_{t=1}^N t \binom{N}{t} p^{N-t} (1-p)^t.
\end{align*}
I can use Stirling's to simplify the $\binom{N}{t}$ term, and then exponentiate both sides to get
\begin{align*}
    \prod_{t=1}^N \exp\biggl( \frac{N^t}{(t-1)!} p^{N-t} (1-p)^t \biggr) \leq e^d.
\end{align*}
However, this does not take me closer to solving for $p$ as a function of $d$, and $N$.

First of all, inequalities are not functions since multiple inputs could yield a true result. Second, you can not use Stirling's formula to "simplify" the binomial coefficient. Stirling's formula is an approximation to factorials when the value is extremely large (i.e. $n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}e^{-2\pi n}n^n$ for large n). This will not work in your case.
Third, you have the expression for the expectation of a probability distribution: the binomial distribution. I'm just going to go ahead and say that the expected value of this is well known: $E[X] = np$, where n = # of Bernoulli trials, and p = probability of success. Okay, so now your problem is trivial: $np \leq d$, solve for $p$.
The non-trivial part is wondering why $E[X] = np$ in the first place. Well, the expected value for the binomial distribution is given by $\sum_{t=1}^{N} t\binom{N}{t}p^t(1-p)^{N-t}$ which you had correct (I swapped the order of $t$ and $N-t$ since it makes it easier).
I'm not going to repeat the proofs of the many ways you can do that, because I don't have enough background of the course you are in and it would be repeating material already presented elsewhere on this site and the internet. Here is one such source: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_of_Binomial_Distribution
